# C99 and floating point environment

Tags: floating-point, c99

I was looking at new features of C99 and saw the floating point environment:

```
#include <fenv.h>
```

My question is simple. If I'm performing floating point number computations, do I have to include the above preprocessor directive in my code? If no, then what does this directive do and when does it become important to include?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to include the fenv.h header if you intend to use any of the features it provides. Those features are described [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/fenv.h.html)-

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not very related, but C++11 now also includes support for C99 floating point environment functions via the [`cfenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) header.